# Error with custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have made a custom annotation in java that takes one value (String[]);

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation{
    String[] value ();
}
```

however, I want the values-when I use MyAnnotation-to be like this: aClassName.anAttribute

- aClassName is the name of a class in my application
- anAttribute is one of it's attributes which is a String:

  `public static String anAttribute1="aStringxxx";`

But I get an error: `The value for annotation attribute MyAnnotation.value must be a constant expression`
Does anyone have an idea please?

Comment: Make the attribute final.

Comment: Did you mean to make value a `String[]` rather than `String` ?

Comment: Thank you ^^ I added final to the attribute and the error desappeared!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the attribute `final` it will work just fine.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static final String myAttribute = "abc";
}

@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] value();
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    @MyAnnotation({SomeClass.myAttribute})
    private int someInt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to mark `anAttribute1` as a `static final` to make it a constant expression.

```
class MyAttributeConstants {
  public static final anAttribute1 = "someString";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but AFAIK you can not use constants which are defined in the same class that uses the annotation.

Possible solution: move the constants to a helper class